# Progress Bar Do Work Backgroundworker C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, backgroundworker, progress

hope anybody can help me. My problem is the progress bar in C# WinForms. I have the following Code:

(There is a stupid calculate from an uint until a given number from a textbox and i want to show the progress while the calculate method is running)

// The stupid method which calculate

```
public void ueberlaufUint()
{
    try
    {
        uint ueberlaufZahl = Convert.ToUInt32(textBox1.Text);
        do
        {
            ueberlaufZahl++;
            //Console.WriteLine(ueberlaufZahl);
        } while (ueberlaufZahl <= 100);

        label1.Text = "Endzahl: " + ueberlaufZahl;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Only not negative natural numbers accepted");
    }
}
```

// Buttonclickevent

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    ueberlaufUint();
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;

    var progress = new Progress<int>(v =>
    {
        // This lambda is executed in context of UI thread,
        // so it can safely update form controls
        progressBar1.Value = v;
    });

    // Run operation in another thread
    await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progress));

    
}
```

// DoWork

```
public void DoWork(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    // This method is executed in the context of
    // another thread (different than the main UI thread),
    // so use only thread-safe code
    for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
    {
        ueberlaufUint();

        // Use progress to notify UI thread that progress has
        // changed
        if (progress != null)
            progress.Report((j + 1) * 100 / 100000);
    }
}
```

The progressbar only counts few steps with no dependency (in my meaning) with the calculate method.

Very great thanks in forward, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: There's no BackGroundWorker here. -- You cannot access Controls in your `ueberlaufUint()` method. If you need the value of `textBox1.Text`, convert it beforehand and pass it to the `DoWork()` method. You can access Controls in the IProgress handler.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response... How is this meaned? Do i need a Backgroundworker and put in my method there?

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo. You have an extra 0 in the code:

```
progress.Report((j + 1) * 100 / 100000);
```

should be

```
progress.Report((j + 1) * 100 / 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you Mike67 :) this solves the problem that my progress bar is filling complete.. but is there a dependency between the function and the prgress bar?